# how do i send emails using mail-gun in my express app

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

i new to mail-gun i'm trying to send an email after successful payment, but each time the payment is cofirmed , i don't get an email

this how i use it

```
const domain = 'https://app.mailgun.com/app/sending/domains/sandbox18d7fe3d7f4c6baf525.mailgun.org ';

var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ 
    apiKey: "MY_APIKEY", 
    domain: domain 
});
```

this is my email template

```
  stripe.charges
    .create(newCharge, function(err, charge) {
      // send response
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.json({ error: err, charge: false });
      } else {
        var emailTemplate = `Hello ${newCharge.shipping.name}, \n

Amount: ${newCharge.amount} \n
Thank you!`;
        // compose email
        var emailData = {
          from: "no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com",
          to: req.body.email,
          subject: "Bundle of Sticks Receipt - " + charge.id,
          text: emailTemplate
        };

        // send email to customer
        mailgun.messages().send(emailData);

        emailData["to"] = "your_support_email@gmail.com";
        emailData["subject"] = `New Order: Bundle of Sticks - ${charge.id}`;

        // send email to supplier
        mailgun.messages().send(emailData);
        // send response with charge data
        res.json({ error: false, charge: charge });
      }
    })
```

how can i go about this , the payment is always successful but the email dont go through

Comment: `mailgun-js` is deprecated, so perhaps look at something better maintained? But other than that, start by actually adding error handlers to your code to see if sending the mails is failing somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `nodemailer` and `nodemailer-mailgun-transport` and work with those.

And using those it will work a little something like this:

```
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import * as mailGun from 'nodemailer-mailgun-transport';

const auth = {
        api_key: <YOUR_API_KEY>
        domain: <YOUR_DOMAIN>,
      }

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailGun(auth));

const mailOptions = {
      sender: "John Doe",
      from: email,
      to: '<WHATEVER_EMEIL>',
      subject: '<YOUR_SUBJECT>',
      text: '<YOUR_TEXT>',
    };

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

Just edit those to suit your need and variables, but that's generally the approach.